# "Оптимизируйте свое приложение для планшетных ПК"

Tags: android, google-play

В девелопер консоли написанно:

> Дизайн страниц должен предусматривать
> максимальное использование
> пространства на экране 10-дюймового
> планшетного ПК.
>
> Загрузите
> скриншоты для планшетных ПК: Добавьте
> хотя бы один скриншот в описание
> приложения для 7-дюймовых планшетных
> ПК.

Ну со скринами понятно. Разве что только: 1) **подойдут скрины с 8 дюймовки?** 2) **Скрины делать в альбомной или портретной ориентации?**

А вот с первым пунктом я ничего не понимаю. Вроде сделано c помощью Fragment -ов. Что ему не нравится. Главный и единственный экран приложения состоит из ViewPager -a. **Что нужно сделать, чтобы "побороть" этот пункт?**

p.s. вот само приложение на [**гитхабе**](https://github.com/danpetruk/Parrally_pipeD_of_Fate/tree/master/src/dlp/parrallypiped) (оно небольшое, почти весь ui в MainActivity).

Comment: 1. Да, без проблем.  
2. На маркете для планшетов я вижу только в ландшафтной ориентации (видимо, это, по-Вашему, альбомная) - горизонтально.

Answer (score 1):

Это просто совет. Даже если вы "оптимизируете приложение для планшетных ПК", это уведомление не пропадет, пока вы его сами не закроете. Оно совершенно не зависит от самого приложения и показывается тупо для всех.

По поводу скринов: никто никогда в жизни не узнает, с чего вы делаете скриншот - с 4" телефона, или с 42" телевизора со смарт приставкой. У изображений (большинства) нету данных о физическом размере. Я всегда, когда мне неважно делать скрины с планшета или попросту влом, заливаю еще раз те же самые с телефона.

Comment: Когда я сижу с планшета в гугл плее, я вижу у некоторых приложений "оптимизированно для телефонов". Ну и соответственно они не попадают в раздел гугл плея "оптимизированно для планшетов". Как избавится от этой надписи?